# Grid battleship board - How do I insert newline characters at certain points?

Tags: ruby, syntax

I'm building battleship while teaching myself Ruby.
In my board class I populate all of the cells in a range (1..4, "A".."D"), so it comes out as "A1", "A2", "A3", etc... The letters show the row, and the numbers show the column.

Now, what I'm trying to do is to render the board. I thought I could take my hash of cells, seperate the keys(the alpha-numeric coordinate) and insert a newline character after each letter combination ends (A's, then B's on \n, and C's on \n, etc...)
I can make it work in a very static way, but what I'm not sure is how to make it more dynamic to match the board - To allow a custom sized board.
My current output looks like this when I call board.cells...

```
{"A1"=>#<Cell:0x007f8edf3231e0 @coordinate="A1", @fired=false, @render=**".", @ship=nil**>,
"A2"=>#<Cell:0x007f8edf323118 @coordinate="A2", @fired=false, @render=**".", @ship=nil**>,
"A3"=>#<Cell:0x007f8edf323000 @coordinate="A3", @fired=false, @render=**".", @ship=nil**>,
"A4"=>#<Cell:0x007f8edf322ee8 @coordinate="A4", @fired=false, @render=**".", @ship=nil**>,
"B1"=>#<Cell:0x007f8edf322da8 @coordinate="B1", @fired=false, @render=**".", @ship=nil**>,
"B2"=>#<Cell:0x007f8edf322cb8 @coordinate="B2", @fired=false, @render=**".", @ship=nil**>,
"B3"=>#<Cell:0x007f8edf322ba0 @coordinate="B3", @fired=false, @render=**".", @ship=nil**>,
"B4"=>#<Cell:0x007f8edf322a88 @coordinate="B4", @fired=false, @render=**".", @ship=nil**>,
...C...D...etc...}
```

I'm currently working on rendering the board, so my logic was if I can get the cells to split on each different letter (cell.keys[0]), then I will be able to work on triggering the @render and manipulating it from there.

Please tell me if my logic is crap :) I need feedback to learn. Also, if you know how to make the \n work in the way I'm thinking, can you point me in the right direction? If I'm thinking about it wrong, please explain.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try group_by

```
%w(a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 c1 c2 c3).sort.group_by{|e| e[0]}
```

A more complete answer:

```
%w(a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 c1 c2 c3).sort.group_by{|e| e[0]}.each{|k, v| v.each{|e| print "#{k}=>#{e} "}; puts}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say this is your class:

```
class Cell
  attr_accessor :fired, :coordinate, :render, :ship

  def initialize(coord)
    @coordinate = coord
    @fired = false
    @render = '='
  end

  def fired!
    @fired = true
    @render = 'x'
  end

end
```

and you define your table Hash:

```
n = 4
rows = (:a..:z).first(n)
cols = (1..n).to_a
cells = rows.product(cols).map(&:join)
#=> ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"]
table = cells.map { |coord| [coord, Cell.new(coord)] }.to_h
```

Let's fire one cell:

```
table["c3"].fired!
```

This is an option you could render the table (unless you mess up the Hash by changing the order of the cells):

```
table.values.map { |cell| cell.render }.each_slice(n).to_a
# [["=", "=", "=", "="], ["=", "=", "=", "="], ["=", "=", "x", "="], ["=", "=", "=", "="]]
```

Or as a string:

```
puts table.values.map { |cell| cell.render }.each_slice(n).map(&:join).join("\n")
# ====
# ====
# ==x=
# ====
```